# Does pathos only work utilizing a pool? I'm looking to get around a pickle issue with multiprocessing.queues

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, dill, pathos

I'm trying to create a series of worker threads that have specific jobs. The current is to draw from a queue, do some processing, and put the output in a second queue.

When I try to use the multiprocessing (multiprocess? what's the difference?) module I get the following issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 264, in _feed
    send(obj)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup     __builtin__.function failed
```

It seems to be a cpickle issue of some kind. I am processing objects with `__getattr__` overwritten but I did use

```
if name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'):
        return object.__getattr__(name)
```

to ensure that the `TypeError` is not called anymore. The answer to pickling issues with multiprocessing is to use `pathos` but I don't see a way to access any kind of queues in `pathos`. I also don't see a way to spawn a `Process` in `pathos`. Every example I've seen uses a `pool`. I also saw a response that there is `pathos.helpers.mp.process.Process` but the modules cannot be found for me - `ImportError: cannot import name helpers`, for example.  Is this something possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the `pathos` author.  Yes, you can use a `Process` from `pathos`, however, if that is what you are interested in, it's probably easier to just use `multiprocess`.  Some disambiguation: `multiprocess` is a fork of `multiprocessing`, where the fork replaces `pickle` with `dill` -- and there's no other changes.  `pathos`, then adds an additional layer on top of `multiprocess`, primarily on the `Pool` objects.  `pathos.multiprocessing` is the additional layer on top of `multiprocess`… and if you want direct access to `multiprocess` from `pathos`, you can get it.  See:

```
>>> import pathos
>>> pathos.helpers.mp.Process
<class 'multiprocess.process.Process'>
>>> 
>>> import multiprocess as mp
>>> mp.Process
<class 'multiprocess.process.Process'>
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I get the following issue exception when I try that `AtributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'helpers'`.   I tried playing with some things and it seems that another huge issue I'm having is that you cannot share `lxml` instances with different processes, even if the object itself can `pickle`.

Comment: Do you have a recent version of `pathos` from github?  (i.e. you didn't install the pathos release, you installed `pathos` master from github)

Comment: currently its moved to: import pathos.multiprocessing as mpm; mpm._ProcessPool.Process

Comment: @RobertGrzelka: It's not moved. It's found at both locations.

Comment: xD I was looking for it using: help(pathos.multiprocessing); and there it was at the end of text... It would be nice to have it accesible from pathos.multiprocessing directly :P

Comment: @RobertGrzelka: yes, maybe some reorganization would be useful